How to disable InfluxDB console logs spamming journalctl in .NET 8.0 application running as systemd
I am using InfluxDB.client in my .NET 8.0 worker application. When running the code using dotnet run, I do not get the logs below. When I compile it to a selfcontained application and run it using systemd on the controller it fills up the journalctl on the controller with these messages every time a datapoint is sent to the server:
Sep 04 02:52:12 compulab-imx8mp TSLogger[1138]: Flushing batches before shutdown.
Sep 04 02:52:12 compulab-imx8mp TSLogger[1138]: The data was successfully written to InfluxDB 2.
Sep 04 02:52:12 compulab-imx8mp TSLogger[1138]: The batch item: OnNext(RestSharp.RestResponse) was processed successfully.
Sep 04 02:52:12 compulab-imx8mp TSLogger[1138]: The WriteApi was disposed.
Sep 04 02:52:12 compulab-imx8mp TSLogger[1138]: The data was successfully written to InfluxDB 2.
Sep 04 02:52:12 compulab-imx8mp TSLogger[1138]: The batch item: OnNext(RestSharp.RestResponse) was processed successfully.
Sep 04 02:52:12 compulab-imx8mp TSLogger[1138]: The WriteApi was disposed.

Relevant InfluxDB Code:
string tokenInfluxDb = cabinetConfig.InfluxDb.Token;
        string urlInfluxDb = cabinetConfig.InfluxDb.Url;
        org = cabinetConfig.InfluxDb.Org;
        bucket = cabinetConfig.InfluxDb.Bucket;

        clientInfluxDb = new InfluxDBClient(urlInfluxDb, tokenInfluxDb);

var point = PointData
                            .Measurement(item.Cage)
                            .Field(item.MeasurementId, value)
                            .Tag("sn", item.SerialNumber)
                            .Timestamp(DateTime.UtcNow, WritePrecision.Ns);

                            LogToDb(point);

async void LogToDb(PointData point) {
        using (var writeApi = clientInfluxDb.GetWriteApi())
        {
            writeApi.WritePoint(point, bucket, org);
        }
    }

Worker.csproj:
<TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
<PackageReference Include="InfluxDB.Client" Version="4.14.0" />

systemd service file:
[Unit]
Description=InfluxDBWorker

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30
WorkingDirectory=/home/usr/application/InfluxDBWorker
ExecStart=/home/usr/application/InfluxDBWorker/InfluxDBWorker
Restart=always
# Restart service after 60 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=60
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=InfluxDBWorker
User=root
Environment=DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I have tried setting different logging parameters to warning in Environment variables and in appsettings.json, but it seems like these are coming from elsewhere.
I tried setting ForwardToConsole=no in journald.conf.
I have not been able to disable this. I found this: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-csharp/issues/560 , but I could make it work.
